# Find the series of $f(x) = x^3\arctan(x^3)$ around $x=0$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Am I correct?

$$x^3\arctan(x^3)$$ 
$$\frac{d}{dx}\arctan(x^3) = \frac{3x^2}{x^6+1} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}3x^2(x^6)^n$$

$$x^3\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}3x^2(x^6)^n$$
$$f(x) = x^3\arctan(x^3) = 3x^5\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(x^6)^n$$

Comment: Your second series is that of the "derivative" of $\arctan x^3$ not just  arc tangent of $x^3$.

Comment: And your series should be an alternating series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $X $ such that $X^2 <1$,

$$\frac {1}{1+X^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^nX^{2n} $$
and by integration

$$\arctan (X)=\arctan (0)+\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac {(-1)^nX^{2n+1}}{2n+1} $$

replace $X $ by $x^3$ and you can finish and get

> $$f (x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac {(-1)^nx^{6n+6}}{2n+1} $$

for $x $ such that $|x|<1$.